# FSM to add two integer

Tags: automata

**Design a Mealy machine to add two integer(binary number).**

I can not determine how to deal with the carry.And what to do with the last carry generated.

Comment: I don't know much about these things, but maybe these notes will be helpful: http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/Cooper/Languages%20and%20Machines/CHAP04%20Introduction%20to%20FSAs.pdf

Comment: Have you had a look at those notes?

Comment: Yes I've checked those notes and can solve other problem related to mealy m/c..but in this problem I deal with the indermediate carry but can't figure out the last generated carry bit

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:
[image: A mealy machine for binary addition]

**Edit**. The two numbers are written in inverse binary notation and you may need to add an extra zero in the front. For instance, suppose you want to add $22$ and $13$. In binary notation, $22$ is $10110$ and $13$ is $1101$. In inverse binary notation, $22$ is $01101$ and $13$ is $1011$. Add $0$ at the end of $01101$ and $00$ at the end of $1011$ and then write the two numbers as follows
$$
  \begin{matrix}
0&1&1&0&1&0 \\
1&0&1&1&0&0
  \end{matrix}
$$
Starting from the initial state, you now have the following path
$$
0 \xrightarrow{(0,1)\mid 1} 0 \xrightarrow{(1,0)\mid 1} 0 \xrightarrow{(1,1)\mid 0} 1 \xrightarrow{(0,1)\mid 0} 1 \xrightarrow{(1,0)\mid 0} 1 \xrightarrow{(0,0)\mid 1} 0
$$
Giving the output $110001$ which is $35$ in reverse binary notation.

Comment: suppose 1111+1010=(1)1001 when the MSB is not generated,then it is in state 1 then o/p is 1001.then it also left a 1(MSB).how to print that 1.Am I clear?

Comment: This is why I said that you may need to add an extra zero in the front.