# Design a finite state machine that performs the serial addition of three arbitrary binary numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, computational-mathematics, automata

Design a finite state machine (by its transition diagram) that performs the serial addition of three arbitrary binary numbers.

For a finite state machine for two binary numbers I got it, but for 3 numbers I'm considering an input set like

$\{000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101, 110, 111\}$

I am considering two states, a carry state and a non-carry state, however I think I need more states for this problem. Could someone provide me with a solution?

Comment: No finite state machine can add arbitrary numbers.

Comment: Don't you need to restrict the number of digits?  You've implied this but please make it explicit as to a maximum number of digits.

Comment: You can add arbitrary numbers if you enter the inputs simultaneously: first all the 1s digits, then all the 2s digits, then all the 4s digits, etc. It may help to try adding three numbers together in base 2 by hand to see what information you need to keep track of.

Comment: @copper.hat See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, three states are needed for adding three binary integers.

First, write the integers in *reverse* binary and potentially add zeros to make the three representations the same length. For example, if $n_1 = 38$, $n_2 = 53$ and $n_3 = 55$, write $n_1$ as $011001$ (since $2 + 4 + 32 = 38$), $n_2$ as $101011$ (since $1 + 4 + 16 + 32 = 53$) and $n_3$ as $111011$ (since $1 + 2 + 4 + 16 + 32 = 55$).

Next, write the three representations one below the other
\begin{align*}
 &011001\\
 &101011\\
 &111011
\end{align*}
and count the number of 1 bits in each column to obtain the following word on the alphabet $\color{blue}A = \{\color{blue}0, \color{blue}1, \color{blue}2, \color{blue}3\}$
$$
  \color{blue}2 \color{blue}2 \color{blue}3 \color{blue}0 \color{blue}2 \color{blue}3
$$
The sequential automaton which realises the addition is shown below. It has the input alphabet $\color{blue}A$ and the output alphabet $\{0,1\}$. The vertical bars are separators. Thus $\color{blue}3 \mid \color{red}1$ means that on input $\color{blue}3$ the output is $1$.
The states $0$, $1$ and $2$ encode the current carries. Note the final outputs $\color{green}\varepsilon$, $\color{green}1$ and $\color{green}0\color{green}1$ attached to the states $0$, $1$ and $2$, respectively.

In our example, the output is $\color{red}0\color{red}1\color{red}0\color{red}0\color{red}1\color{red}0\color{green}0\color{green}1$, which is the code of
$146 = 2 + 16 + 128.$ And indeed, $38 + 53 + 55 = 146$!

[image]

See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1841238) for adding two binary numbers.